# Construct a Triangle with Triangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry

If you have a very large but finite number of equilateral triangles (of any/all sizes) is it then possible to construct an isosceles triangle? By isosceles I mean a non-equilateral isosceles triangle.

Can you prove/disprove it?

Comment: Exactly what operations are allowed? Do you mean just putting the given equilateral triangles together on a plane?

Comment: Yes, just putting them together. No overlaps, no gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> **impossible**. It still holds if we're allowed to overlap the triangles or leave a hole inside the isosceles triangle, as long as only the exterior boundary is considered.

It is because simply

> a union of any number of equilateral triangles has all internal angles of 60 degrees or larger, but a non-equilateral isosceles triangle (or *any* non-equilateral triangle) necessarily has an internal angle smaller than 60 degrees.